# Mercurial [auth] section

Tags: authentication, mercurial, push

I'm new to mercurial, and I'm trying to set up `hgrc` in such a way that I can push to the Google Code repository without having to type the password each time. I could just specify a `https://user:pass@project.googlecode.com/` repository under `paths.default`, but that seems messy. Thus, I'm trying to use the [`[auth]`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#auth) section, which, from what I can tell, is recommended over the first solution. So far I've set it up like this:

```
[auth]
myproject.prefix = myproject.googlecode.com/hg
myproject.username = my.username
myproject.password = ******
myproject.schemes = https
```

But I don't know where to go from here. Trying to push gives:

```
abort: repository default-push not found!
```

I somehow have to specify the default repository to use (myproject), or something like that, but how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer myself. It seems Mercurial smartly matches entries in `[auth]` with entries in `path`. In this case, a correct `hgrc` would be:

```
[paths]
default = https://myproject.googlecode.com/hg
[auth]
myproject.prefix = myproject.googlecode.com/hg
myproject.username = my.username
myproject.password = ******
myproject.schemes = https
```